# Bigger output than expected

Tags: c++, c++11

I needed a program where a user orders items but the output was wrong. It was outputting 12-digit numbers when I only needed 2-3 digits. Why is it outputting bigger numbers than expected?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    //Order
    int Pfries = 80, Pburgers = 150, Pdonuts = 30, Picecream = 25, Psoftdrinks = 20;
    int Nfries, Nburgers, Ndonuts, Nicecream, Nsoftdrinks;
    int fries = Pfries * Nfries, burgers = Pburgers * Nburgers, donuts = Pdonuts * Ndonuts, icecream = 
    Picecream * Nicecream, softdrinks = Psoftdrinks * Nsoftdrinks;
    string customer;
    cout<<"Welcome to Murakani Cafe!"<<endl;
    cout<< "Enter the name of the customer: ";
    cin>>customer;
    cout<< "Enter the number of fries ordered:";
    cin>>Nfries;
    cout<< "Enter the number of burger(s) ordered: ";
    cin>>Nburgers;
    cout<< "Enter the number of donut(s) ordered: ";
    cin>>Ndonuts;
    cout<< "Enter the number of ice cream ordered: ";
    cin>>Nicecream;
    cout<< "Enter the number of soft drink(s) ordered: ";
    cin>>Nsoftdrinks;


    //Output
    cout<< "Hi "<< customer << "! Here is the summary of your order:"<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<< Nfries << "    fries    "<< Pfries << fries <<endl;
    cout<< Nburgers<< "    burgers    "<< Pburgers << burgers<<endl;
    cout<< Ndonuts<< "    donuts    "<< Pdonuts << donuts<<endl;
    cout<< Nicecream<< "    ice cream    "<< Picecream << icecream<<endl;
    cout<< Nsoftdrinks<< "    soft drinks    "<< Psoftdrinks << softdrinks<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int fries = Pfries * Nfries` But `Nfries` is uninitialized at this point. Don't use it before the user entered it at `cin>>Nfries;`.

Comment: Please read [why warnings are important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) then look at [your program being compiled the right way with two mainstream compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/boz438).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the order you do things matters. This is OK

```
int Pfries = 80;
cout<< "Enter the number of fries ordered:";
cin>>Nfries;
int fries = Pfries * Nfries;
```

because at the point where you calculate `fries` both `Pfries` and `Nfries` have values.

But this (which is what you do) is not OK

```
int Pfries = 80;
int fries = Pfries * Nfries;
cout<< "Enter the number of fries ordered:";
cin>>Nfries;
```

In this calculation you use the `Nfries` variable **before** it has been given a value. This is technically known as *undefined behaviour*, which is another way of saying that the effects of this code are unpredictable.

What you seem to be thinking is that you've written a formula `fries = Pfries * Nfries` and C++ will recalculate that formula if any of the variables get different values. But that's not how C++ (or most programming languages) work. Instead your program is a sequence of statements which get executed in a given order, and the values used are the values that the variables have at the time when the given statement is executed.